# Broker API calls from website without including lib and config in Bin

Tags: 2011, broker, api

In 5.3 Tridion we had few Basic Broker API calls and component link, but there was no lib and config in bin, it was working fine

now while moving to 2011sp1, it throw error if these two folders are not there in bin. if i include it works fine.

Is there any way in 2011 to avoid having these in bin, Reason our all app dlls are part of CMS so we publish it from CMS.
then i have to include all 70 odd jar into CMS.

Comment: a CMS should not be considered a deployment tool IMO, so I think the reasoning behind you having DLLs inside your CMS is a bit off.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In 5.3 you were using .NET with Interop to COM with Interop to Java (and along with this you had a lot of other limitations like the COM calls being single-threaded and god knows what else).

As from Tridion 2009 we removed the COM dependency, so your .NET API calls use in-process interops to Java, with a significant performance improvement - but the side-effect of this is that you need IIS to host the Java side of Tridion, and this is why you need the jars in your bin/lib.

Alternatively you could consider using the Content Delivery WebService instead of the Tridion API, but this would probably require re-thinking your application model.

So, in short: no, you cannot avoid having these in bin.

Comment: What happened to the TRIDION_HOME environment variable? That is still supported isn't it?

Answer (score 4):

Although Nuno is correct in saying your problem cannot be avoided it can be mitigated:

the pain of having to put 70 jars in Tridion would be greatly reduced by making use of Tridion's webdav feature; you could simply copy in all 70 jars via Windows Explorer (I usually do this for images also) assuming your jar files are represented by multimedia components of course...

Comment: jikes, are you suggesting to upload all jars in the CMS and then deploy them by publishing? That really is confusing (and abusing) a CMS with a deployment tool.

Comment: I'm not suggesting anything; the poster is; I quote:
  Reason our all app dlls are part of CMS so we publish it from CMS. then i have to include all 70 odd jar into CMS.

Comment: And I would also say that this is not really the place for a discussion about whether to use Tridion as a deployment tool or not :) There are many of them out there and different people have radically different opinions on this topic...

Comment: yeah I see that now, granted WebDAV makes that process easier (no matter how wrong it is indeed ;o)